# CurlException failed creating formpost data

Tags: php, facebook

i'm trying make photo upload, but i'm not getting, well the goal was publish in my fan page wall, i cann't, so i decided to test in my wall "me/photo", same thing, this error appears!

**CurlException failed creating formpost data**

this is my code, and the page "config.php" contains only configurations, appid, secret, etc...

anyway, What am i do wrong?

```
  $photo = '/imagens/teste.jpg'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
  $message = 'Photo upload via the PHP SDK!';

?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($idUsuario) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
        // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
        // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'access_token'=> $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                                         'source' => '@'.$photo,
                                         'message' => $message
                                         )
                                      );
        echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
        echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

You can see that this code is the same  code example in dvelopers.facebook to make upload!

Answer (score 0):

You must send the realpath to the API.

Change:

```
$photo = '/imagens/teste.jpg';
```

By:

```
$photo = realpath('/imagens/teste.jpg');
```

And check if your path is good.

Comment: I am having the same problem here, after adding the real path it shows me the error "No URL set!"